# Некорректный рендеринг шрифта Nunito

Tags: css, шрифты, render

1. Межбуквенное расстояние
   Обнаружилась проблема с рендерингом шрифта Nunito в браузерах по сравнению с Figma: при отображении в браузере шрифт более узкий.
   Это скриншот со сверстанной страницы (выше браузер, ниже фигма)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это с гугл фонтс (выше браузер, ниже фигма). Ситуация аналогичная, т.е. проблема не в некорректном подключении шрифта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Отображение нечетных кеглей
   Также есть проблема при отображении шрифта с нечетным размером, например кегль 13px, обратите внимание на буквы “к” и “л”, концы обрезаются.
   Скриншот с верстки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот с гугл фонтс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать эти глюки? Спасибо

Comment: Я конечно не дизайнер, но отмечу очевидный факт: на скриншотах сравниваются _разные_ шрифты. Различается начертание букв в, ы, й, а, н, ...

Comment: Обратись к автору шрифта..... Не возможно исправить ни чем....

Comment: А межбуквенное расстояние  регулирует [letter-spacing](http://htmlbook.ru/css/letter-spacing)